# Haskell duplicate the value in a list according to its position

Tags: haskell

I am pretty new to Haskell. I am trying to write a program that takes a list and returns a list of one copy of the first element of the input list, followed by two copies of the second element, three copies of the third, and so on. e.g. input `[1,2,3,4]`, return `[1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]`.

```
import Data.List

triangle :: [a] -> [a]
triangle (x:xs)
    |x/=null   = result ++ xs
    |otherwise = group(sort result)
    where result = [x]
```

I try to use `++` to add each list into a new list then sort it, but it does not work. What I tried to achieve is, for example: the list is `[1,2,3]`, `result = [1,2,3]++[2,3]++[3]` but sorted.

Comment: have a look at [`zipWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith) and [`replicate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:replicate) and [`concat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concat) - a good start is trying `zipWith (\i x -> something_with_replicate...) [1...] youList`

Comment: It looks to me like you're trying to *update* `result` using `++`. That's not the way Haskell works. Variables are all immutable, so when you say `result = [x]`, that means `result` is always going to be `[x]`; that won't change. You need to think *functionally*, calculating the result you want rather than trying to change anything.

Comment: @dfeuer to me, that code is absolutely incomprehensible. but I think I could glean from the _example_ the OP's intention, which is kind of nice, geometrical and abstract actually. the resulting code is very concise!  (since the functionality happens to exist already, implemented in (more than one) library). and it also does no counting of its own -- at all! :) (it's in my answer, in case you haven't seen it)

Answer (score 2):

here is a short version

```hs
triangle :: [a] -> [a]
triangle = concat . zipWith replicate [1..]
```

### How it works

`zipWith` takes a function `f : x -> y -> z` and two lists `[x1,x2,...]` `[y1,y2,..]` and produces a new list `[f x1 y1, f x2 y2, ...]`. Both lists may be infinite - `zipWith` will stop as soon one of the list run out of elements (or never if both are infinite).

`replicate : Int -> a -> [a]` works like this: `replicate n x` will produce a list with `n`-elements all `x` - so `replicate 4 'a' == "aaaa"`.

`[1..] = [1,2,3,4,...]` is a infinite list counting up from `1`

so if you use `replicate` in `zipWith replicate [1..] [x1,x2,...]` you get

```
[replicate 1 x1, replicate 2 x2, ..]
= [[x1], [x2,x2], ..]
```

so a list of lists - finally `concat` will append all lists in the list-of-lists together to the result we wanted

the final point: instead of `triangle xs = concat (zipWith replicate [1..] xs)`  you can write `triangle xs = (concat . zipWith repliate [1..]) xs` by definition of `(.)` and then you can *eta-reduce*  this to the *point-free* style I've given.

Comment: Got it, can u please explain why it works?

Comment: I added an explanation - hope this helps but to be honest you should just take the parts and play with them

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```hs
triangle :: [Int] -> [Int]
triangle = concat . go 1
    where
        go n [] = []
        go n (x:xs) = (replicate n x) : (go (n+1) xs)
```

Comment: if we're writing it in the direct style already, we can forgo the `concat` by replacing `:` with `++`.

Answer (score 0):

*update:* now I see what you mean here. you want to take diagonals on `tails`. nice idea. :) Here's how:

```
import Data.Universe.Helpers
import Data.List             (tails)

bar :: [a] -> [a]
bar = concat . diagonals . tails
```

That's it!

Trying it out:

```
> concat . diagonals . tails $ [1..3]
[1,2,2,3,3,3]
```

Or simply,

```
>  diagonal . tails $ [11..15]
[11,12,12,13,13,13,14,14,14,14,15,15,15,15,15]
```

---

<sub>*(previous version of the answer:)*</sub>

Have you heard about list comprehensions, number enumerations `[1..]` and the `zip` function?

It is all you need to implement your function:

```
foo :: [a] -> [a]
foo xs = [ x | (i,x) <- zip [1..] xs, j <- .... ]
```

Can you see what should go there instead of the `....`? It should produce some value several times (how many do we need it to be?... how many values are there in e.g. `[1..10]`?) and then we will ignore the produced value, putting **`x`** *each time* into the resulting list, instead.